# Azure file share mapping on user startup fails when VM StoppedDeallocated

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files

I am trying to automatically map Azure file share when VM starts up. The VM is set to login automatically and the script is on the user start up folder. The credentials are stored persistently.
cmdkey /add:.file.core.windows.net /user: /pass:
It works if the VM is rebooted but fails if it is shutdown completely with System error 1231. If I RDP and run the script it works. Does the shutdown cause any corruption?

```
@ECHO OFF 
net use Z: /delete
net use Z: \\share.file.core.windows.net\fileshare

timeout /t 10 /nobreak
START  "" "Z:" 
START "MyService" Z:\service\MyService.exe
```

Comment: Adding a  "timeout /t 15 /nobreak" before the first command seems to fix it for VM shutdown. I added that to allow some time if the network isn't ready when the script runs. However, it is still failing (now with System Error 53) when I change the VM size and reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and the main cause of error was the actual network not being available when the script runs during log on. I was able to map it by catching the error message and retrying in a loop. I logged the errors and it seems to map correctly after few attempts. The final script is as following.

```
@ECHO OFF 

if not exist Z:\ (
timeout /t 5 /nobreak

:loop
net use Z: \\share.file.core.windows.net\fileshare

if errorlevel 1 (
echo "Mapping failed"
timeout /t 5
goto loop
) else (
echo "Mapping Successful" 
)

) else (
echo "Mapped already"
)

START  "" "Z:" 
START "MyService" Z:\service\MyService.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first persist the storage account credentials on the virtual machine if you want it to reconnect on reboot.  Here is the command to run on the virtual machine.  More details available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/).

```
cmdkey /add:<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net /user:<storage-account-name> /pass:<storage-account-key>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add but I tried making it persisting as you mentioned before. It gave the same error message. Isn't the username and password on net use command similar to making it persistent?